# Paypal - ExpressCheckout - The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts (10413)

Tags: php, error-handling, paypal, express-checkout

I'm using the following and getting the same error over and over again; and notice: both AMT and ITEMAMT = $paymentAmount.

I cannot, for the love of $deity, understand WHY aren't the amounts matching.

```
$grandtotal = 0;
for ($i = 0;$i < $numItems;$i++) {
    $subtotal = $theBasket[$i]['item_preco'] * $theBasket[$i]['item_qty'];
    $grandtotal += $subtotal;
    echo $subtotal.'<br>';
    $mCq .= '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME'.$i.'='.htmlentities($theBasket[$i]['item_nome']).
        '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT'.$i.'='.$theBasket[$i]['item_preco'].
        '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY'.$i.'='.$theBasket[$i]['item_qty'];
}
```

for loop returns this:

&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=HAMSÁ BRACELET RING

&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=9

&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1

```
$paymentAmount = number_format($grandtotal,2);

        $nvpstr = $mCq;
        $nvpstr .= '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT='.$paymentAmount;
        $nvpstr .= '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT='.$paymentAmount;
        $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=" . $paymentType;
        $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&RETURNURL=" . $returnURL;
        $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&CANCELURL=" . $cancelURL;
        $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=" . $currencyCodeType;
```

Comment: Can you include an example transaction which doesn't work?

Comment: how come? I think i provide that already, in "for loop returns this". If not, im not understanding what you are asking.

Comment: And what's in the `$grandtotal` and `$paymentAmount` variables?

Comment: $grandtotal = 9
$paymentAmmount = 9.00
$subtotal = 9

Comment: Since you found the answer yourself, why not specify it as an answer rather than posting it within your original post? Then tick it as the considered answer.

Comment: at the time, i couldn't answer my own questions. I think because of points. I don't know. but i did that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. I got it fixed. The thing is: the error it says it has it's not the error that "breaks the link".

Instead of this being a 10413 (total amounts whatnot whatever) This is a simple case of "field is missing"; In this case, `'&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER'.$i.'='.$theBasket[$i]['ct_item_id']. '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC'.$i.'=descricao'.` Those where the ones missing